# How to invoke multiple processes and wait for one to finish in C?

Tags: c

I have 3 executables which are programmed also in C, and now I want to create a wrapper process, which will invoke the others. More specifically, I want to invoke 1 copy of the first and third process, and 10 copies for the second process. And additionally, I want to wait for the first process to finish with execution. The idea is that these processes once invoked they send messages between themselves and communicate using ZMQ library, and once all messages are exchanged they terminate. I started with something like this, trying to run just my first process:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void) {
  pid_t parent = getpid();
  pid_t pid = fork();

  if (pid == -1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: failed to fork.\n");
    exit(1);
  } else if (pid > 0) {
    int status;
    waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
  } else {
    char *args[] = { "0", "10" };
    char *env[] = { NULL };
    execve("./first", args, env);
    _exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

But this either doesn't invoke the first process or doesn't wait for it. The reason is that if one invokes just the first process, it should not terminate at all, it should enter infinite loop, as it tries to connect to my second process, which in this case is not invoked. However, my above code finishes execution immediately. What's the proper way to invoke 12 processes in total, from which they are composed of 3 different type of processes, and wait until one of them is finished?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char *args[] = { "0", "10" };
```

That's wrong. The kernel doesn't magically know where that ends, so it's reading too far and making the `execve` fail. That makes the child do `_exit(EXIT_FAILURE);`, and with it dead, the parent's `wait` returns, so it returns too. To fix it, change that to this:

```
char *args[] = { "0", "10", NULL };
```

Also, you probably didn't mean for `argv[0]` to be `"0"`, so actually change it to this:

```
char *args[] = { "./first", "0", "10", NULL };
```

Comment: I see, thanks, this solved the issue that my process is called now. But, my other part of the question remains. How can I call 3 different processes, and multiple processes with one process, and only wait for specific one of my choice?

Answer (score 0):

regarding your second question:

Save each and every generated process `pid` in an array of

```
pid_t  childPids[10];
```

then the index into that array is the child process you want to wait for.

To wait for a specific child:

```
int x = <which child you want to wait for>
int status;
waitpid( childPids[x], &status, 0 );
```